# #Flutter the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly

Tags: flutter, dart

While running my flutter app, it works fine but after sometimes I'm getting the error below:

```
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
#1      DefaultResidentCompiler._compile.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/compile.dart:771:13)
#2      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1180:38)
#3      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
#4      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
#5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:392:13)
#6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:402:15)
#7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:286:7)
#8      _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:98:11)
#9      _EventSinkWrapper.close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:25:11)
#10     _StringAdapterSink.close (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:251:11)
#11     _LineSplitterSink.close (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart:136:11)
#12     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:143:24)
#13     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1180:38)
#14     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
#15     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
#16     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:392:13)
#17     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:402:15)
#18     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:286:7)
#19     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:98:11)
#20     _EventSinkWrapper.close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:25:11)
#21     _StringAdapterSink.close (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:251:11)
#22     _Utf8ConversionSink.close (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:302:20)
#23     _ConverterStreamEventSink.close (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:83:18)
#24     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:143:24)
#25     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1180:38)
#26     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
#27     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
#28     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:392:13)
#29     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:402:15)
#30     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:286:7)
#31     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendDone (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:787:19)
#32     _StreamController._closeUnchecked (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:644:7)
#33     _StreamController.close (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:637:5)
#34     _Socket._onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1989:21)
#35     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1196:13)
#36     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
#37     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:987:7)
#38     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
#39     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:266:7)
#40     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:779:19)
#41     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:655:7)
#42     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:597:5)
#43     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1534:35)
#44     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1012:18)
#45     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
#46     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
#47     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#48     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)

[{"event":"app.stop","params":{"appId":"68806365-e542-4635-9e22-33f15caa4633"}}]
```

Flutter doctor: **Doctor no issues found**

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

Anyone knows how to solve this? Help please.

Comment: So running the same app with the same code multiple times causes this error?The info provided isn't enough to discover the problem I think

Answer (score 0):

I had the following error and the only way I fixed it was by just doing  as follows:

```
flutter clean
```